# Replace class name from elements having the class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to replace a class name from all the elements with the class name?

```
<div id='sddiv'>
    <span class='open'>sometext</span>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    <span class='open'>sometext</span>
    <div class=''></div>
    <span class='closed'>sometext</span>
    <div class=''></div>
</div>
```

So, I tried doing it like this.

```
var elms=document.getElementById('sddiv').getElementsByClassName('open');
for(i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
    elms[i].classList.add('closed');
    elms[i].classList.remove('open');
}
var elms=document.getElementById('sddiv').getElementsByClassName('sub');
for(i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
    elms[i].classList.remove('sub');
}
```

This kind of works. But, is there any way to do this with out the looping and no jQuery as I have problem using it.

Comment: You should use `querySelectorAll('.classname')` and inside your loop you should use `elements.item(i)` to get the element instead of `elements[i]`. And you can't do this without looping. Also, you should really consider jquery as its as easy as `$(".classname").removeClass("classname").addClass("otherclassname");`

Comment: @somethinghere But jQuery also does a loop internally – it is just a wrapper to hide that implementation.

Comment: @feeela Yes but you do't have to worry about getting it right. Theres a reason why this stuff exists - this is good to know, but doesn't work on older browsers, yet jQuery will take care of that for you. It comes down to: _don't reinvent the wheel_.